# How to launch XSS if routing use $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI" and explode "/"

Tags: php, security, xss

What I mean:

http://kjventura.com/2011/11/make-pretty-urls-with-php-url-routing/

I use this system on my site (development stage). With urls like:

```
site.com/tag/lorem
```

as example I have output "lorem" into h1 tag on the webpage.

But how launch simple alert() with this URl scheme? I dont escape anything (deliberately)

Comment: XSS works when user submitted content (be it via URL, GET, POST, COOKIE, from a DB, from an API, whatever) is displayed on the page. In this case, unless you echo out your parts of the URL you are likely OK. Depending on what you do next (e.g. echo file_get_contents($uri[1]);) then you may be vulnerable to directory traversal attacks.

Comment: Passing a URL-encoded `<script>` tag on the end of your string to the `<h1>` will cause it to be decoded and inserted into your HTML, and the browser then executes it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You should better double check that. Because it won’t be decoded automatically as PHP does with URL parameters.

Comment: @Gumbo Ah yes, correct.  I didn't read the link (or the title I guess) and assumed `$_GET` was being rewritten into.

Comment: So in this use case, via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` it may not be vulnerable, but it is essential to get into the habit [of using `htmlspecialchars()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) around user input strings sent back to the browser to mitigate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the unchanged URI as it appeared in the request line, the characters that can get passed depend on what characters are allowed in a URI path, more precisely in a [path segment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3):

> ```
> segment       = *pchar
> pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
> ```

Where *pct-encoded* is a [percent-encoded octet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1), and *unreserved* as well as *sub-delims* are defined as follows:

> ```
> unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>             / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

These allowed characters are not sufficient for a Cross-Site Scripting attack when the injection occurs in the content of an HTML element like in your case a `<h1>…</h1>`. You would at least need a `<` to be able to create a start-tag.

However, if you would decode the percent-encoded octets, any character could be passed.